# PHPStorm + XAMPP + XDebug on Windowsの設定で躓きました

Tags: xampp, phpstorm

[こちらの動画](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VL60RCKv7lQ)を参考に設定中です。

2:24の時点でServerNameを記述する箇所があるのですが、
動画説明ではits up to youと書いてあり何をかけばいいのか分かりません。

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
ServerName ■ここに何をかけばいいのか分かりません
<Direcotory "C:\xampp\htdocs">
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Direcotory></virtualHost>
```

どなたか分かる方お教えいただけないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。
windows 10 64bit xamppのバージョン 7.1.4

Comment: サーバ名は、DNSまたは、hostsに設定されているドメイン名を書きます。（アクセスする時に使うサーバ名です。例、ja.stackoverflow.com　とか　stackoverflow.com）ドメイン名を仮に付けるならhostsファイルにIPとアクセスするドメイン名を指定すればよいです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。DNSはXserverに設定しているのでそれを記述しようと思います。ローカル環境だけでPHPの統合環境ができると思っていたのですがそうではないのですね。勉強になりました。

Comment: ローカル環境なら、hostsファイ‌​ルにServerNameで指定したドメインを設定し、ブラウザのURL欄にhttp://hostsに設定したテスト用のドメイン/　でアクセスできます。動画の3:10あたりでhosts設定説明していますよ。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
なにやら難しく考えすぎていました。